# Google Mock - mocked object fails to build in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, googletest, googlemock

I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60486110/how-to-set-up-both-googletest-and-googlemock-in-visual-studio)'s second option to set up gmock in Visual Studio. Here's the whole `test.cpp` file.

```
#include "pch.h"

class ServiceBus {
public:
    void publish(int x);
};

class MockServiceBus : public ServiceBus {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(publish, void(int x));
};

class Example {
private:
    ServiceBus bus;

public:
    Example(ServiceBus& bus) : bus{ bus } {}

    void call_bus() {
        bus.publish(0);
    }
};

TEST(AutoBrakeTest, shouldTestMock) {
    MockServiceBus bus{};
    Example example{ bus };
    EXPECT_CALL(bus, publish(::testing::_));
    example.call_bus();
}
```

This code produces the following error.

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall ServiceBus::publish(int)" (?publish@ServiceBus@@QAEXH@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Example::call_bus(void)" (?call_bus@Example@@QAEXXZ)   MyProjectTesting    C:\Users\pavli\source\repos\MyProject\MyProjectTesting\test.obj 1
```

If I comment out the line `example.call_bus();` from the TEST function it compiles just fine. I'm fairly new to C++ and this causes me major headaches. Can you help?

Comment: Probably you need to either add `= 0;` to declaration of `publish()` in `ServiceBus` or to add definition of `ServiceBus::publish()` function. Also, `publish()` should be defined as `virtual` for gmock to work properly.

Comment: Thanks @sklott. I come from Java background so I wasn't aware of these requirements.